# java regex to Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I am now very knowledgeable in Javascript nor with regular expressions. I have the following regex that works for me in Java:

```
"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+|(?=[0-9])(?=>[a-zA-Z])"
```

If I use this regex to split the String `"20aa#$%20b#$%20a#$%20c#$%20d#$%20e#$%20f#$%20g`" using the String.split() method it will meet the expected output `[20aa,20b,20a,20c,20d,20e,20f,20g]`.

However the same procedure does not work in Javascript, therefore my question is: which is the equivalent procedure in Javascript?

Thank you for your attention

Comment: It works for me

Answer (score 0):

Your regex works. `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+|(?=[0-9])(?=>[a-zA-Z])/g`

```js
var result = "20aa#$%20b#$%20a#$%20c#$%20d#$%20e#$%20f#$%20g".split(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+|(?=[0-9])(?=>[a-zA-Z])/g)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you, the regex works with dashes / instead of double quotes "